# How set web.config for 2 domains with same root folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a Window server 2019, RAM 2GB, 64bit

What I would like is this

```
http://ibz-love.com
http://www.ibz-love.com
https://ibz-love.com
https://www.ibz.com
```

Forward to https://www.ibz-love.com
and

```
http://simone-peluquero.es
http://www.simone-peluquero.es
```

forward to http://www.simone-peluquero.es

Both domains will have the same css, js, pages but different database so contents

Until when I had just 1 it worked this

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Do It All" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
                <add input="{SERVER_PORT}" pattern="^80$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But now I would like a another for my other website and to filter them by the domain request
How Can I do?
Thank you

Comment: Duplicate the contents and use two physical locations for the two sites please. That saves you from all the trouble.

Comment: Are ibz-love and simone-peluquero both on the same server?

Comment: @LexLi there s a reason, it's a cms

Comment: @DingPeng yes in my server, they forward to the same directory

Comment: Disk/storage space is much cheaper than messing up your server configuration.

Comment: @LexLi if course, I did it more for updated reasons, I mean when I will committ new updates all my client's websites will be updated. Anyway, is not possible to filter in some way the request call of the browser? I m not expert of web.config but if a user calls a domain instead of another it's not possible detect that and so filter from the config? thank you

Comment: You can use the HTTP_HOST field in the conditions to match the domain you need to filter.